# How to prefill a form by using fields from a table, getting additonal user data, and write new record to different tbl

Tags: ms-access, vba

I’m trying to prefill a template for teachers to enter student grades.

The teacher will identify the Class, and/or Section and I will retrieve every student in those classes and/or sections. Each student will appear on a row in the template and the teacher will then fill in the grades.

I plan to retrieve the student info from the existing Student table and write this data into the EnterGrades table. After the teacher fills in the grades I will write these records from the EnterGrades table into the master grades table.

I’m having a problem figuring best method – query, form, what type. I tried to add some sql code to a form, but I couldn’t get it to work in VBA. It seems relatively straight forward, I just can’t quite see the solution. I’m first time Access user.

Answer (score 0):

Using a form based on as you said Temp table is how I tend to do enter data.  In the properties of the form under DATA Tab look for RECORD SOURCE.  Then the fields can be set by Data Tab again Control Source.

Form Wizard should actually work well for you.

What do you mean by Pre-filled?  As in has Default text? I use a lot of Combo Boxes with options and make sure that none of them are empty then have a button to submit.  Run a query to update the master table and then empty the table.

If you are using .mdb
Create a module and add the following code.  (Might have to add Tools>Reference. Microsoft DAO Library.)

It will run any query for you.  [Param1],[Param2]... in the query where you want to fill in criteria dynamically.  Call it by simply

```
fncQueryRun "QueryName", 0
 or
fncQueryRun "QueryName", 1, "John Smith"
```

I copy this code to every new database I make if it has a form.

My favorite module code is:

```
Public dbTemp As Database, rstTemp As Recordset, tblTemp As TableDef
Public qryTemp As QueryDef, prmTemp As Parameter 
Public bQueryError  As Boolean, bError3271 As Boolean

Public Function fncQueryRun(ByVal stQueryName As String, ByVal intParamCnt As Integer, _
  ParamArray Param() As Variant)

  On Error GoTo Err_fncQueryRun

  bQueryError = False
  Set dbTemp = CurrentDb
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    If intParamCnt = 0 Then DoCmd.OpenQuery stQueryName  'Runs Query
      'Parameter Count 0 = Just Runs the Query
    If intParamCnt >= 1 Then Set qryTemp = dbTemp.QueryDefs(stQueryName)
    If intParamCnt >= 1 Then qryTemp.Parameters![Param1] = Param(0)
    If intParamCnt >= 2 Then qryTemp.Parameters![Param2] = Param(1)
    If intParamCnt >= 3 Then qryTemp.Parameters![Param3] = Param(2)
    If intParamCnt >= 4 Then qryTemp.Parameters![Param4] = Param(3)
    If intParamCnt >= 5 Then qryTemp.Parameters![Param5] = Param(4)
    If intParamCnt >= 6 Then qryTemp.Parameters![Param6] = Param(5)
    If intParamCnt >= 7 Then qryTemp.Parameters![Param7] = Param(6)
    If intParamCnt >= 8 Then qryTemp.Parameters![Param8] = Param(7)
    If intParamCnt >= 9 Then qryTemp.Parameters![Param9] = Param(8)
    If intParamCnt >= 10 Then qryTemp.Parameters![Param10] = Param(9)
    If intParamCnt >= 1 Then qryTemp.Execute dbSeeChanges


  DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Exit_fncQueryRun:
  Set qryTemp = Nothing
  dbTemp.Close
  Exit Function

Err_fncQueryRun:
  bQueryError = True
  If Err.Number = 3271 Then
      bError3271 = True
      Resume Exit_fncQueryRun
  ElseIf Err.Number = 3070 Then
      Resume Exit_fncQueryRun
  Else
      MsgBox "Query named " & stQueryName & " -  Had error number: " & Err.Number & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
        & Err.Description, , "Query - " & stQueryName & " -  Error: " & Err.Number
      Resume Exit_fncQueryRun
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: What is the point of `"ByVal intParamCnt As Integer"`? To see how many elements are included in `Param()`, use `UBound(Param)` and add one.  To see how many parameters are expected by the query's SQL, use `qryTemp.Parameters.Count`